# How do I get all of the websites visited from this packet?

Tags: networking, wireshark, icmp

[image]

I’m trying to find all the websites visited along with their IP srs and destination addresses but all I’m getting is a “No response found!”.

PS: I am given the .pcap file so I can’t modify it.

Also using the ICMP protocol, any help?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqaYQ.png

Comment: Are you trying to get the URLs that go along with those IP addresses, or is there some other content you're pulling from? Also, have you tried reverse DNS searches?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to get the URLs that match those IP addresses or requests! I'm a newbie so sorry for my beginner-like questions! Please help :/

Comment: And no I haven't tried reverse DNS searches , will that help?

Comment: Then you need to use reverse DNS. DNS normally takes a web address and gives you the IP address that it points to. Reverse DNS just does the reverse: It takes an IP address and gives you the site (or sites) that are hosted there.

Comment: Any recommended tools? How do I get started with that? Or do I have to do it manually? And hey thank you so much for your kind help!! :)

Comment: A google search will show you quite a few decent reverse dns services that can get you started. Select one on the front page and you'll probably be well on your way.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example of what you have and what you expect to get. Please note that you’ve currently applied a filter in Wireshark that may hide more meaningful packets.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the use of the ICMP protocol - that is really only used for ping and connectivity checking type things.

In order to check what websites are visited, you need to enable TCP (particularly on port 80), then inspect each packet for the "host:" header which will tell you the address.

Another partial solution (which can help with HTTPS sites, but also inject other unrelated sites) would be to monitor port 53 (UDP + TCP, mainly UDP) to get the DNS requests which will tell you what hosts are being asked for.